Pants build system failed to read link to python in venv
I just created a new venv where I updated python to version 3.12 and am now encountering problems with creating a docker image with pants
When I ran pants package on a python file I got this error message
Engine traceback:
  in `package` goal
IntrinsicError: While expanding link "new_venv/bin/python": Failed to read link "/home/danielw/guru/new_venv/bin/python3.12": Absolute symlink: "/usr/bin/python3.12"

The path to python3.12 is valid so I don't know how to fix this problem
